# How to filter coordinates from a .csv file?

Tags: r, coordinates, histogram

I created a histogram using the data that I have for an entire country, but I now only want data for a specific region. I created a bounding box, but not sure how to incorporate this in the code or if it is even useful.

This is what I have so far, but I do not know how to filter within a specific long and lat:

```
hist(Year,breaks=seq(floor(min(Year)), ceiling(max(Year))), 
     main= "Fires hotspots from 2000 to 2020", xlab="Year", col= "#cc0000",border= "#000000")
```

Both longitude and latitude have their own columns.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have a look at https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?

Answer (score 0):

long and lat are continuous variables, so if you know your `max longitude`, `min longitude`, `max latitude` and `min latitude` you can create a subset of your original dataframe by creating a logical vector which satisfies your conditions regarding long and lat:

```
lat_conditions = (df$lat < max_lat) | (df$lat > min_lat)
long_conditions = (df$long < max_lat) | (df$long > min_lat)

combined = lat_condition & long_condition
your_desired_object= df[combined,]
```

Now `your_desired_object` contains a subset of your original dataframe which are all confined to your min max lat long coordinates, and you can freely plot your histogram( by plotting `your_desired_object`) now that all irrelevant observations are not in the subset.